# What's causing this error?

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, bsod, desktop-computer, windows-error-reporting

A pc I am working on ran great till 20 minutes ago, when the following happened:

I insterted a usb flash drive with a file and tried to search something on the internet when I noticed the mouse cursor was moving with lag spikes. My first thought was that either the CPU was overworking or the ram was getting full. So I restarted the PC.

Instead of the PC opening, it played a rapid sound (*faster than when there is no ram on*) and I started checking all the things connected to it, only to find out that when the usb keyboard gets connected this sound starts. If I connect a keyboard with no usb gate but the original circle purple one it makes no sound.

BSOD also appeared with a BAD POOL HEADER error.

What do you think is the cause?

P.s. there were 4 or 5 current shortcuts today, but I don't know if these are connected to it.

Update: A friend of mine accidentaly fixed it when he inserted 2 keyboards. Now the issue happens only when you put the old keyboard or another one that propably does not work. Still don't know why.

Comment: Is the problem occurring when the flash drive is inserted?

Comment: I removed the flash drive when the PC was having the above lag spikes. Now I have deleted it contents and I have given the usb flash drive back. The error keeps happening, it seems hardware-ish. So what exactly is your thought?

Comment: It could be a problem with the powersupply. The USB stick needs additional power to run which is the symptom. I would advise to turn off the pc, unplug the powercord, press and hold the powerbutton for 5 seconds with the cord unplugged (to ensure that all power is out of the system) then plug the cord back in and see if the issue still remains.

Comment: @LPChip tried this. Didn't work.